# Enlarge select row height

Tags: html, css

I'm making a touch interface and need to enlarge the select form (In order to make the rows eaiser to hit with the clumpsy finger). Is there any other way of enlarging the select rows without enlarging the text font? I know that the select is very limited, and you might suggest using a diffrent approach. I'm aware of that. I'm just curious if there are a way to enlarge the  row without enlarging the font text. =)

On the image below I have

```
font-size: 20px;
```

[image]

And I would prefer it to be around 14-16, but then the rows would be rather hard to hit on a touch screen.

Full css code of the dropdown menu below

```
.styledDropDown select{
    background: transparent;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: 0px;
    height: 31px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
}

.styledDropDown{
    float:right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 31px;
    background:url(../images/bedview/dropDown.png) no-repeat;

}
```

Could only change background color and font color but not change padding

```
option { 
background-color:#ddd; /*Works*/
margin:20px; /*don't work*/
padding:20px; /*Don't work*/
}
```

Edit it works in Internet Explorer but want it to work in chrome :/

Comment: Apply padding to the `option` tag.

Comment: Could you link us to a working example?

Comment: Didn't work, could just change background color, and font color, but could not change padding on option tag :/

Comment: You need some select replacement like: http://lab.aspektas.com/select/select.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you only need it for chrome

You can try something like

http://jsfiddle.net/nyd69/3/

Obviously it's not the best result but this i the best I got

```
select {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Chrome doesn't support giving styles to option.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `<select>` and it's OK.
Try to modify `width` and `height` in CSS to see changes.
I have tested in FF but not Chrome.
Can you check this [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/HMHV4/) if it's OK or not?
Thanks.